# How to process huge JSON data from Webservice in C#.Net

Tags: c#, web-services, json, .net-3.5

I have a Coldfusion Webservice that returns json data like below:

```
{"rows":[{"cell":[43,"USA","jon","doe","doe@gmail.com","HR"],"id":43},
{"cell":[44,"JAPAN","tanaka","yidi","yidi@aol.com","IT"],"id":44}],
"page":1,"records":2,"total":1}
```

I like to consume this Webservice from .Net using C#, and insert data into Sql server 2008.  Json data returned from webservice could be up to 30 MB and I'm not so sure how to handle this.  Please let me know best way to do this.

Comment: JSON.NET: http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JsonTextReader](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) in JSON.Net should be helpful in efficiently processing this large data stream.  Does the webservice return it in a single shot?

There is a recent benchmark [here](http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/03/parsing-twitter-json-comparing-c.html) by somebody who had the same problems as you, plus some sample (test) code.  Looks like JSON.Net came out pretty well.

EDIT:

```
string jsonData = webservice.Request(params);
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonData));
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yes webservice will return in one shot.  Is there any other way to return?  I would really need a sample code to look into.  Plase let me know if you have one.  Thanks,

Comment: @amj, nope - I don't know how you would get web service to not do this  in one go - sorry

Comment: oh ok. what i still don't know is how to pass data return from webservice to jsontextreader?

Comment: @amj - if you have a string in hand from the webservice, look at my EDIT for something like what's needed.